# How to get spec name to be used as output file name in protractor-html-reporter-2?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm using protractor html reporter 2 for my reporting. I need to get spec name as html report output file name.

i'm using the below code in my config file.

```
var today = new Date(),
timeStamp = today.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + today.getDate() + '-' + today.getFullYear();
onPrepare:
 function () 
{
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    var fs = require('fs-extra');        

    scriptName=function(){
        return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){
        return config.specs;
        });
    };

    fs.emptyDir('./target/htmlReports/'+scriptName+'-'+timeStamp+'/screenShots/', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
        specDone: function(result) {
            //if (result.status == 'failed' || result.status == 'passed') {
            if (1==1) {
                browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                    var browserName = userData.testUser.browser.toUpperCase();

                    browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                        var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./target/htmlReports/'+scriptName+'-'+timeStamp+'/screenShots/'+ result.fullName+'.png');
                        stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                        stream.end();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });



    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: 'target/XMLReports',
        filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
    }));

},

onComplete: function() {
    var browserName, browserVersion;
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

    capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
        browserName = userData.testUser.browser.toUpperCase();
        platform=caps.get('platform');
        browserVersion = caps.get('version');


        testConfig = {
            reportTitle: 'Test Execution Report',
            outputPath: './target/htmlReports/'+scriptName+'-'+timeStamp,
            screenshotPath: './target/htmlReports/'+scriptName+'-'+timeStamp+'/screenShots',
            testBrowser: browserName,
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            outputFilename:'ProtractorTestReport',
            testPlatform: platform,
            //browserVersion: browserVersion,
            modifiedSuiteName: true,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: false
        };
        new HTMLReport().from('./target/XMLReports/xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
    });
},

plugins: [{
    package: 'jasmine2-protractor-utils',
    disableHTMLReport: true,
    disableScreenshot: false,
    screenshotPath:'./target/htmlReports/'+scriptName+'-'+timeStamp+'/screenShots',
    screenshotOnExpectFailure:true,
    screenshotOnSpecFailure:true,
    clearFoldersBeforeTest: true,
    htmlReportDir: './target/htmlReports'

}],
```

i tried with 
`browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(config){
            console.log(config.specs);
        });`
,it returns

> [ 'D:\projects\HeartlandSSP\Automation\TenantManagement\Ssp.TenantManagement.Protractor_Test\specs\createTenantSpec.js',
>     'C:\Users\renusri.rajalingam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\__protractor_internal_afterEach_setup_spec.js' ]

but the actual spec name **createTenantSpec.js**  is not returning. I need only the filename of the spec and not the name of the describe or it functions. Since I have 5 specs, i need to generate separate report with its spec name. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `config.specs` is an array and according to output we have the file's absolute path is at index `0`. So the file name can be extracted as follows.

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {
  var fullName = config.specs[0];
  var fileName = fullName.substring(fullName.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  console.log('fileName:', fileName);
});

// output: 
// fileName: createTenantSpec.js
```

Or if you would like to have all file names in this array you could use this:

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {
  var fileNames = config.specs.map(function(path) { 
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1); 
  });
  fileNames.forEach(function(fileName) {
    console.log('fileName:', fileName);
  });
});

// output:
// fileName: createTenantSpec.js
// __protractor_internal_afterEach_setup_spec.js
```

References:

`array.prototype.map()` => [click me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map%20array.prototype.map())

`array.prototype.forEach()` => [click me](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)

Comment: i tried with the above code replacing var fullName = config.specs; (which actually returns the mentioned array output above) but still it returns undefined. i couldn't extract the name.

Comment: @Renu Well, I did not see it is an array. I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in on Complete:

```
browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) 
{
            var fullName = config.specs[0];
            console.log('fullName' ,fullName);
            var start= fullName.lastIndexOf('\\');
            var stop=fullName.length;
            console.log('start:', start);
            console.log('stop:', stop);
            var fileName = fullName.substring(start+1,stop);
            console.log('fileName:', fileName);
           
});
```